# How to get orders that have a coupon code applied using woocommerce rest api

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce-rest-api

Hi I am using the woocommerce sdk to get all the orders that have a coupon applied.For example I have a coupon code named 'testcoupon'. I have applied the coupon on 3 orders. Then how we can get the three orders where the coupon code 'testcoupon' that has been applied. I have tried the below code

```
 $coupon_code = 'testcoupon';
$order_status = 'completed';
$query_params = [
    'coupon_code' =>[ 'code' => $coupon_code ],
    'status' => $order_status,
];
$completed_orders = $woocommerce->get('orders', $query_params);
```

but it's giving all the orders that are completed instead of orders that have 'testcoupon' code applied.is the format correct?